# Automatically create an eisenhower matrix from a task list

Tags: vba, excel, matrix

I am trying to automate my to-do list in Excel, using VBA to create an [Eisenhower matrix](http://www.eisenhower.me/eisenhower-matrix/).

I have constructed my to-do list in the following way:

```
Task | Urgent | Important | done
 T1  |   x    |    x      |  
 T2  |        |    x      |  
 T3  |   x    |           |  
 T4  |        |           |
```

I am able to filter my task list on both urgency and importancy, and exclude the rows which are indicated as "done".

I want to create my matrix in such a way that it looks like this:

```
__________|IMPORTANT|NOT IMPORTANT
URGENT    |   T1    |     T3
----------|---------|--------------
NOT URGENT|   T2    |     T4
```

I don't know how to code my VBA in such a way that it selects my filtered rows, determines how large the matrix will be, and populates it accordingly.

I am trying to count the amount of rows using the `range.count()` property in excel VBA but I can't get T2 and T4 aligned. Also, it copies the 'task' header each time as well.

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
Sub populate_matrix()
Dim i As Integer

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$55").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="="
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$55").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$55").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>"

Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
i = Range(Selection).Count
Selection.Copy
Sheets("work matrix").Select
Range("B2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Sheets("tasks").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$55").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="="
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$55").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$55").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="="

Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("work matrix").Select
Range("B" & i).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Sheets("tasks").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$55").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="="
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$55").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$55").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="="

Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("work matrix").Select
Range("c2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Sheets("tasks").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$55").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="="
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$55").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="="
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$55").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="="

Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("work matrix").Select
Range("C" & i).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

End Sub

Comment: Please add what you've done so far. And you should use `Range.Rows.Count` if you are trying to count rows! ;)

Answer (score 0):

edited after OP's code updating

you can try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub main2()
    Dim EisenTable As Range

    Set EisenTable = Worksheets("work matrix").Range("B2:C3")
    With Worksheets("tasks")
        With .Range("D1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
            EisenTable.Cells(1, 1) = CountX(.Cells, 2, 3, "x", "x")
            EisenTable.Cells(1, 2) = CountX(.Cells, 2, 3, "x", "<>x")
            EisenTable.Cells(2, 1) = CountX(.Cells, 2, 3, "<>x", "x")
            EisenTable.Cells(2, 2) = CountX(.Cells, 2, 3, "<>x", "<>x")
        End With
    End With
End Sub

Function CountX(rng As Range, col1 As Long, col2 As Long, crit1 As String, crit2 As String) As String
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim iVal As Long

    With rng
        .AutoFilter Field:=col1, Criteria1:=crit1
        .AutoFilter Field:=col2, Criteria1:=crit2
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                ReDim vals(1 To .Count) As String
                For Each cell In .Cells
                    iVal = iVal + 1
                    vals(iVal) = cell.Value
                Next
            End With
            CountX = Join(vals, ",")
        End If
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Function
```